# Rails: Thread won't affect database unless joined to main Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I have a background operation I would like to occur every 20 seconds in Rails given that some condition is true.  It kicked off when a certain controller route is hit, and it looks like this

```
def startProcess
    argId = self.id
    t = Thread.new do
        while (Argument.isRunning(argId)) do
            Argument.update(argId)
            Argument.markVotes(argId)
            puts "Thread ran"
            sleep 20
        end
    end
end
```

However, this code does absolutely nothing to my database unless I call `"t.join"` in which case my whole server is blocked for a long time (but it works).

Why can't the read commit ActiveRecords without being joined to the main thread?
The thread calls methods that look something like

```
def sample
  model = Model.new()
  model.save()
end
```

but the models are not saved to the DB unless the thread is joined to the main thread.  Why is this?  I have been banging my head about this for hours.

EDIT:

The answer marked correct is technically correct, however this edit is to outline the solution I eventually used.   The issues is that Ruby does not have true threading, so even once I got my DB connection working the Thread couldn't get processor time unless there was little traffic to the server.

Solution:  start a new Heroku worker instance, point it at the same database, and make it execute a rake task that has the same functionality as the thread.  Now everything works great.

Comment: There are better ways to do background jobs. [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-establish the database connection:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection Rails.env
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply! Where do I call this, and what is the reason for this?

Comment: In the new thread, somewhere before you start writing to the database. I'm not sure why it is necessary -- I've had to do it with forks because connections aren't shared amongst processes and I'm guessing in your case they aren't shared amongst threads.

Comment: Wow that is interesting.  Is there some way to tell it to take the database config from my database.yml or do I have to copy and paste?

Comment: Updated my answer. It can take a string as a parameter to point to the entry in your database.yml, usually named after your rails env.

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili Just trying to understand why would a thread need a separate activerecord connection shouldn't it suppose take  that same connection from main process

Comment: I think there are problems with this approach, among them the assumption that activerecord is thread safe.